# Could someone help me debug my app (not very big)?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Not sure if this kind of help is accepted to ask for here, tell me if it isn't.

It has to get done before tomorrow, it's not entirerly finished but it should work somewhat ok by now. I'm trying to use the Eclipse debugger (not very used to it).

OK, I had an old class called "Debugging" in another project folder, which was a debugging-test. I didn't give it that name, it was an assignment. It seemed to cause some problems, removed it and now my stacktrace is much smaller.

I tried debugging the Board constructor, added the original code from the constructor into a method and tried running that method in the constructor. Which doesn't make any difference, but still.

Now the stacktrace looks like this:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
Board(Object).<init>() line: 20 
Board.<init>() line: 9  
Game.<init>() line: 15  
Game.main(String[]) line: 11
```

The board constructor:

public class Board {

```
private int COLUMNS = 8;
private int ROWS = 8;
private Square[][] grid;

public Board(){
    addGrid();
}

public void addGrid(){
    grid = new Square[COLUMNS][ROWS];
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++){
            grid[col][row] = new Square(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The square constructor:

```
public class Square {

    private Piece piece;
    private Board board;

    public Square(Board b){
        board = b;
    }
```

Among my breakpoints I noticed this:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: caught and uncaught
```

Tried again and got something similar as before:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 217   
ClassNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available 
ClassNotFoundException.<init>(String) line: not available   
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(String) line: not available   
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
Board.addGrid() line: 14    
Board.<init>() line: 10 
Game.<init>() line: 15  
Game.main(String[]) line: 11
```

Comment: Sure, I added first part of the Board class. I tried starting at a breakpoint, right at the first line of the Board constructor. It gives me pretty much the same exception.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, your Game class cannot see the Board class.  If the code sections you posted are correct, it looks like it's because they don't have package declarations at the top of the code.  You need to put something along the lines of this as the first line of your code:

```
package boardGame;

public class Board {
```

etc. at the start of each class.  Also, the package name must be the same as the name of the folder containing the source files.

Comment: Hey, sorry about it. Some class made it seem like a bigger deal then it is, edited my post. Do I still need to put things into a new package?

Comment: Well if you have the correct package declaration at the top it will work, that's all I was saying.  Another question: which line is line 20 in the stacktrace you posted?  And what exception or error does it give you when you run the program?